# Wordpress Widgets <a> Link Tags outside the <li> Tag?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

my question is, is it possioble to the link the < li > tags in widgets?

example: normaly the < a > tag is inside the < li > tag:

```
<div class="widget_archive">
    <h3 class="footer-widget-title">Archive</h3>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://url.tld/2013/10/" title="Oktober 2013">Oktober 2013</a>&nbsp;(7)</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

but i want like this:

```
<div class="widget_archive">
    <h3 class="footer-widget-title">Archive</h3>        
        <ul>
            <a href="http://url.tld/2013/10/" title="Oktober 2013"><li>Oktober 2013 &nbsp; (7)</li></a>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**i want that the user can click on the complete element, and not only on the link text.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. It's rendered well in browser's, but is not valid W3C html.

You will get an error like

`Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context.`

if you try to validate in w3C

You can do your validation test through W3C **[HERE](http://validator.w3.org/check)**, you can choose also doctype for validation

```
<div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Link 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Link 2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

li {    
    display: inline;    
}
a {
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;

}
```

Comment: Is there a valid solution?

Comment: With css you should give to the li  `display: inline;`, and to the a the type of display you want to apply usually `block` also to the a you will give `width` and `height`

Comment: I edited my answer for you to better understand, also you can watch a live demo here -> http://jsfiddle.net/HfwKG/